# Deleting List Items By HTTP Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to delete the list items from the collection using HTTP delete method which takes one parameter of id. For simplicity, I have no guard for checking the provided input and just trying to convert it to int. My expectation is, after invoking delete method with id, let's say 1, the item with index 1 must be deleted from my dishes collection. However, get method still returns all the items.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKVdd.png)

Comment: You need to edit the question and add the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Controllers are scoped by default so the constructor is ram and that list of string is recreated after every request. So it will delete but as soon as you make another request it will recreate itself. Try moving that list to a static class and make the list static, then you should get expected behaviour

Comment: That is because you need to save your changes. your controller will not hold changes once your delete request is completed. and for your get request again it will create new object of controller.

Comment: Is ran not “ ram”

Comment: @Nitz - it’s nothing to do with saving changes, there’s no db or “real” persistence layer involved. They’re just manipulating an in memory list

Comment: @scottdavidwalker: it is not a right way of implementing rest API's. just providing static list is not solving the real problem and he is getting wrong ideas. the right way would be to really store the data to a db or a persistence layer. i don't know if he is doing this code for learning or real project. it is fine for learning but if he is doing for project then in my opinion it is not correct way.

Comment: @Nitz - The “real problem” is the problem he’s facing now based on the question. You’re providing an answer based on information that doesn’t exist. Calling SaveChanges would make no sense in this situation. Of course in a real world situation you’d want an actual persistence layer but also in a real situation you wouldn’t be deleting data based on a index. Also, persistence of data is nothing to do with Api Design so I don’t understand the “right way of implementing a rest Api” comment

Answer (score 1):

you could make your dishes list static:

```
private static readonly List<string> dishes = new() { "Oxtail", "Curry Chicken", "Dumplings" };
```

As long your application is running you can remove items and `GetDishes()` will give you the desired result.

As soon as you restart your application you will have the initial 3 items.

If this action should be persistent you need some kind of datastore. E.g. a database

Comment: Thanks it worked. I'd kindly ask you if you could clarify what these three words (private static readonly) did to the collection? I mean why the collection does not get recreated anymore as soon as I invoke GET method?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: because of the static. If something is declared as static it lives as long as the application is running, Thus you can remove items and that is persisted in memory as long as the application is running. 
If the static would not be there on each request the `dishes` variable is newly initialized because of the scoped lifetime of the controller.
`private` because there is no need for a public field.`
`readonly` indicates that assignment to the field can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to an answer.

The issue is that controllers are scoped. Meaning that every time a new request comes in, that class gets recreated which means your list of string also gets recreated as it is an instance variable. So when you’re doing you’re  next “get” you’re doing it on a brand new instance of the class and therefore a brand new instance of that list.

If you make your list static, it should solve the problem as static variables should last the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want any check the simpliest way is

```
 List<string> dishes = new() { "Oxtail", "Curry Chicken", "Dumplings" };
    
var id="Dumplings";

dishes.RemoveAll(d => d == id);
```

or with some check

```
    var itemToRemove = dishes.Where(d => d == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if(itemToRemove != null) dishes.Remove(itemToRemove);
```